# Automate a hyper link to open on a condition

Tags: google-sheets, hyperlink

I have a google sheets that I need to automate opening a hyperlink when cell A2 (a drop down with "OPEN" and "CLOSED" options) is changed to "CLOSED".

Have not attempted this programming this yet in the Google sheets App. Looking for examples